# Upgrade to Azure SDK 1.7 But TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy Still Lookinf for 1.1

Tags: c#, azure

Got error

`Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

Stack

`Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling.AzureStorage.StorageTransientErrorDetectionStrategy.CheckIsTransient(Exception ex) +0
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling.AzureStorage.StorageTransientErrorDetectionStrategy.IsTransient(Exception ex) +21
   Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction(Func`1 func) +557
`

I upgrade my SDK to 1.7, why TransientFaultHandling still looking for 1.1 despite I have a 1.7 version of StorageClient in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment there is no version of TOPAZ supporting the 1.7 SDK. You'll need to add binding redirects in your app.config/web.config to fix this until a new version is released:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.7.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ServiceBus" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.6.0.0" newVersion="1.7.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="101.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.4655.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding> 
  </runtime>
```

Comment: Actually, there is now (as of Aug 21) a new version of the Transient Fault Handling Application Block ("TOPAZ") on CodePlex and Nuget.  It supports Azure SDK v1.7 and adds some critical bug fixes for Service Bus and Cloud Storage.

Comment: Here's the URL to the Release Notes: http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TopazAug2012UpdateReleaseNotes&version=8